# input type number - wrong number format if decimal places are .00

Tags: html, locale

I have input fields that hold currency values (decimal value with 2 decimal places).

If the input has a value 1.34 it is displayed correctly as 1,34 (lang attribute is "de").
If the input has a value 2.00 it is formatted and still shown as 2.00. As soon as the value is changed to something other than .00 it is again displayed correctly with a comma.

```
output is correctly formatted <input type="number" name="dec1" value="1.99" step="any" lang="de" /><br /> output is wrong formatted <input type="number" name="dec3" value="1.00" step="any" lang="de" />
```

So far I can only reproduce this behaviour in Firefox.
Chrome and Safari seem to work fine.

[JSFiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/ojfw57yr/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`<input type="text" id="dec1" onBlur="handler(ev)"/> var handler = (ev) { document.getElementById("dec1").value = ev.target.value.replace(/./g, ","); }`

Comment: have to admit I do not get it to work. The js part keeps telling me that afater var handler =(ev) there is a semicolon missing.